# React promise code need to change a json value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, promise

Need to change data coming back from promise return and add a link wrapper to one of the fields.

This is the React code

```
this.state = {
    medications: [],
}

queryMeds().then((response) => {
   this.setState({medications: response});
});
```

Above returns several records that i see in console as this format (which I need)
(You can see it has json string with fields "value" and "short_description"

```
0: {value: "VICODIN TAB", short_description: "VICODIN TAB 5-300MG"}
```

What I need to do is alter this daily to have a change to the "value" So what I want is

```
0: {value: "<a onClick=jsfunction('VICODIN TAB')>VICODIN TAB</a>", short_description: "VICODIN TAB 5-300MG"}
```

Things that I was trying to do (push and map) ended up giving me

```
0: "VICODIN TAB"
```

Thus both my attempt with a map and a for loop with push is not using value and short_description in a string json

```
response.map((item)=>{
    //adding_list.push( <a onclick={`jsfunction(${item.value}) href=javascript:void(0);`}>{`${item.value}`}</a>);
    adding_list.push(item.value, item.short_description)
});

//Nor 
for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
   let newMedication = response[i].value; //<a onclick={`jsfunction(${response[i].value}) href=javascript:void(0);`}>{`${response[i].value}`}</a>;
   this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
         medications: [...prevState.medications, newMedication]
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: I think you are almost there with the map function, but you do not use it quite correctly, try something this: let mappedResponse = response.map((item)=>{
    ...item, value: '<a onclick={`jsfunction('+item.value+') href=javascript:void(0);`}>{`'+item.value+'`}</a>'
});

Comment: it doesn't like that  { ...   etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close!

The method `map` will return a new (and possibly modified) array, so the first step is to save that in a new variable.

Inside the `map` method, you can transform the item and return the transformed version. So your code should look like:

```
// Mutable version
const modifiedResponse = response.map((item) => {
    const modifiedValue = <a onClick={() => this.jsfunction(item.value)} href="javascript:void(0);">{item.value}</a>;
    item.value = modifiedValue;
    return item;
});


// Imutable version
const modifiedResponse = response.map((item) => {
    const modifiedValue = <a onClick={() => this.jsfunction(item.value)} href="javascript:void(0);">{item.value}</a>;
    return {...item, value: modifiedValue}
});
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: changed to onClick (react )  , but then i get   `Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.`

Comment: When I look at the output of HTML , i see `<a>Vicodin Tab</a>`  seems to be ignoring the jsfunction and href   ... ugh

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have an editor. Updated the answer with proper escape now. Also updated the `onClick` :)

Comment: trying to figure out why it isn't going to that jsfunction ,  i did have to add  this.jsfunction to it,    but it seems the javascript:void(0) is not letting it go to the reaction js function

Comment: Ok got it   had to add arrow function    `const modifiedValue = <a onClick={e=>this.jsfunction(item.value)} href="javascript:void(0);">{item.value}</a>;`

Comment: also , when and why would i want to use immutable version ?

Comment: The `jsfunction` was just copied from your original question, so was hard for me to know how to handle it. I will updated the answer to include it, but glad you figured that out :)

Comment: About immutability, I just wanted to point the difference between the two approaches. In this specific case, since `map` already returns a new object, you probably don't need to worry about mutating the object inside the `map` function. But if you had more operations inside `map`, immutability could become something important. In summary, most of the time is better to use immutability, so you can be sure of what to expect from that object or variable.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> let newResponse = response.map((res)=>{
>     res.value= (<a onClick=jsfunction({res.value})>{res.value}</a>)
>     return res 
> })
> ```

Comment: that doesn't work , needs string escaped or something

Comment: Why the upvotes, this won't work as is.  lot of string and variable escapes to consider